# Wrapping an analytical function in another function in Hive 0.11

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying the following:

> select case when ta_end_datetime_berekenen = 'Y' then lead(ta_update_datetime) over ( partition by dn_waarde_van, dn_waarde_tot order by ta_update_datetime ) else ea_end_datetime end ea_end_datetime, ta_insert_datetime, ta_update_datetime from tmp_wtdh_bestedingsklasse_10_s2_stap2

However, when I try that, I get the following error:

> NoViableAltException(86@[129:7: ( ( ( KW_AS )? identifier ) | ( KW_AS LPAREN identifier ( COMMA identifier )* RPAREN ) )?])
>
> FAILED: ParseException line 1:175 missing KW_END at 'over' near ')' in selection target
> line 1:254 cannot recognize input near 'else' 'ea_end_datetime' 'end' in selection target

Would I be correct in assuming that it's not possible to wrap an analytical function in another function?

This is with Hive 0.11.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the root of your problem, but seems like your query is missing an `AS` keyword (note the all-caps `AS` on line 8 below).

```
select 
    case 
        when ta_end_datetime_berekenen = 'Y' 
    then 
        lead(ta_update_datetime) over ( partition by dn_waarde_van, dn_waarde_tot order by ta_update_datetime ) 
    else 
        ea_end_datetime 
    end AS ea_end_datetime, 
    ta_insert_datetime, 
    ta_update_datetime 
from tmp_wtdh_bestedingsklasse_10_s2_stap2
```